# ModalPopupExtender: Parent page is not disabling

Tags: ajax

I am trying example of ModalPopupExtender. When popup happens, controls at back of popup are not disabled, that is I can still click on button at the back of pop up. Below is the code

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>    
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" DropShadow="true" TargetControlID="Button1"
         PopupControlID="Panel1" BackgroundCssClass="backgroundModalPopup" PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel1">
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="Aqua" Style="display:none">
        This is modal pop up extender : hi
         <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />         
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Can anyone please let me know the reason why I am not able to disable rest of page? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got solution on this. The problem was css was not referred in the aspx page(though I addeed code to link my css file). But weired thing is that when I added css to the aspx page by droping css file onto aspx page in the visual studio it worked and when I referred it through code it didn't worked for me. Really strange!!!

Thanks.